# Calculate the Fourier series with the trigonometry approach

Tags: python, numpy, signals

I try to implement the Fourier series function according to the following formulas:

[image]

...where...

[image]

...and...

[image]

[image]

Here is my approach to the problem:

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as py

# Define "x" range.
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 1000)

# Define "T", i.e functions' period.
T = 2
L = T / 2

# "f(x)" function definition.
def f(x): 
    return np.sin(np.pi * 1000 * x)

# "a" coefficient calculation.
def a(n, L, accuracy = 1000):
    a, b = -L, L
    dx = (b - a) / accuracy
    integration = 0
    for i in np.linspace(a, b, accuracy):
        x = a + i * dx
        integration += f(x) * np.cos((n * np.pi * x) / L)
    integration *= dx
    return (1 / L) * integration

# "b" coefficient calculation.
def b(n, L, accuracy = 1000):
    a, b = -L, L
    dx = (b - a) / accuracy
    integration = 0
    for i in np.linspace(a, b, accuracy):
        x = a + i * dx
        integration += f(x) * np.sin((n * np.pi * x) / L)
    integration *= dx
    return (1 / L) * integration

# Fourier series.   
def Sf(x, L, n = 10):
    a0 = a(0, L)
    sum = 0
    for i in np.arange(1, n + 1):
        sum += ((a(i, L) * np.cos(n * np.pi * x)) + (b(i, L) * np.sin(n * np.pi * x)))
    return (a0 / 2) + sum    

# x axis.
py.plot(x, np.zeros(np.size(x)), color = 'black')

# y axis.
py.plot(np.zeros(np.size(x)), x, color = 'black')

# Original signal.
py.plot(x, f(x), linewidth = 1.5, label = 'Signal')

# Approximation signal (Fourier series coefficients).
py.plot(x, Sf(x, L), color = 'red', linewidth = 1.5, label = 'Fourier series')

# Specify x and y axes limits.
py.xlim([0, 10])
py.ylim([-2, 2])

py.legend(loc = 'upper right', fontsize = '10')

py.show()
```

...and here is what I get after plotting the result:

[image]

I've read the [How to calculate a Fourier series in Numpy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4258106/how-to-calculate-a-fourier-series-in-numpy) and I've implemented this approach already. It works great, but it use the expotential method, where I want to focus on trigonometry functions and the rectangular method in case of calculating the integraions for `a_{n}` and `b_{n}` coefficients.

Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE (SOLVED)**

Finally, here is a working example of the code. However, I'll spend more time on it, so if there is anything that can be improved, it will be done.

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
import pylab as py

# Define "x" range.
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 1000)

# Define "T", i.e functions' period.
T = 2
L = T / 2

# "f(x)" function definition.
def f(x): 
    return np.sin((np.pi) * x) + np.sin((2 * np.pi) * x) + np.sin((5 * np.pi) * x)

# "a" coefficient calculation.
def a(n, L, accuracy = 1000):
    a, b = -L, L
    dx = (b - a) / accuracy
    integration = 0
    for x in np.linspace(a, b, accuracy):
        integration += f(x) * np.cos((n * np.pi * x) / L)
    integration *= dx
    return (1 / L) * integration

# "b" coefficient calculation.
def b(n, L, accuracy = 1000):
    a, b = -L, L
    dx = (b - a) / accuracy
    integration = 0
    for x in np.linspace(a, b, accuracy):
        integration += f(x) * np.sin((n * np.pi * x) / L)
    integration *= dx
    return (1 / L) * integration

# Fourier series.   
def Sf(x, L, n = 10):
    a0 = a(0, L)
    sum = np.zeros(np.size(x))
    for i in np.arange(1, n + 1):
        sum += ((a(i, L) * np.cos((i * np.pi * x) / L)) + (b(i, L) * np.sin((i * np.pi * x) / L)))
    return (a0 / 2) + sum   

# x axis.
py.plot(x, np.zeros(np.size(x)), color = 'black')

# y axis.
py.plot(np.zeros(np.size(x)), x, color = 'black')

# Original signal.
py.plot(x, f(x), linewidth = 1.5, label = 'Signal')

# Approximation signal (Fourier series coefficients).
py.plot(x, Sf(x, L), '.', color = 'red', linewidth = 1.5, label = 'Fourier series')

# Specify x and y axes limits.
py.xlim([0, 5])
py.ylim([-2.2, 2.2])

py.legend(loc = 'upper right', fontsize = '10')

py.show()
```

[image]

Comment: You will learn more if you debug your own code.  (It looks as though you these things as learning exercises, but then right at the point where you'd learn the most, and you'd actually have to think, you post a question to SO, defeating your purpose.)

Comment: I'm an autodidact and I post a question only if I loose battle with myself. Thank you for the tip about debugging. I have not used it so far with Python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider developing your code in a different way, block by block. You should be surprised if a code like this would work at the first try. Debugging is one option, as @tom10 said. The other option is rapid prototyping the code step by step in the interpreter, even better with ipython.

Above, you are expecting that `b_1000` is non-zero, since the input `f(x)` is a sinusoid with a `1000` in it. You're also expecting that all other coefficients are zero right?

Then you should focus on the function `b(n, L, accuracy = 1000)` only. Looking at it, 3 things are going wrong. Here are some hints.

- the multiplication of `dx` is within the loop. Sure about that?
- in the loop, `i` is supposed to be an integer right? Is it really an integer? by prototyping or debugging you would discover this
- be careful whenever you write `(1/L)` or a similar expression. If you're using python2.7, you're doing likely wrong. If not, at least use a `from __future__ import division` at the top of your source. Read [this](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/) PEP if you don't know what I am talking about.

If you address these 3 points, `b()` will work. Then think of `a` in a similar fashion.

Comment: Thank you for the very valuable tips. Finally, I found that I had also a mistake in the `Sf(x, L, n)` function :) Now everything works just great.

Comment: glad it worked out. Consider accepting the answer, and editing the question adding your final working code after the current text (keep the question intact!)