# Python, fourier series of discrete data

Tags: python, numpy, signal-processing, fft

I am trying to Find the Fourier series representation for n number of harmonics of a discrete time data set. The data is not originally periodic, so I performed a periodic extension on the data set and the result can be seen in the waveform below.

[image]

I have tried to replicate the solution in this question : [Calculate the Fourier series with the trigonometry approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27708002/calculate-the-fourier-series-with-the-trigonometry-approach)
However The results I received did not produce a proper output as can be seen in the pictures below. It seems that the computation simply outputs an offset version of the original signal.

[image]

The data set I am working with is a numpy array with 4060 elements. 
How can I properly compute and graph the Fourier series decomposition of a discrete data set?

Here is the code i used, it is almost identical to that in the example referred to in the link, except changes have been made to accommodate my own signal data.

```
 # dat is a list with the original non periodic data
 # persig is essentially dat repeated over several periods

 # Define "x" range.
 l = len(persig)
 x = np.linspace(0,1,l)
 print len(x)

 # Define "T", i.e functions' period.
 T = len(dat)
 print T
 L = T / 2

 # "f(x)" function definition.
 def f(x): 

     persig = np.asarray(persig)
     return persig

# "a" coefficient calculation.
 def a(n, L, accuracy = 1000):
     a, b = -L, L
     dx = (b - a) / accuracy
     integration = 0
     for x in np.linspace(a, b, accuracy):
         integration += f(x) * np.cos((n * np.pi * x) / L)
     integration *= dx
     return (1 / L) * integration

# "b" coefficient calculation.
 def b(n, L, accuracy = 1000):
     a, b = -L, L
     dx = (b - a) / accuracy
     integration = 0
     for x in np.linspace(a, b, accuracy):
         integration += f(x) * np.sin((n * np.pi * x) / L)
     integration *= dx
     return (1 / L) * integration

# Fourier series.   
 def Sf(x, L, n = 5):
     a0 = a(0, L)
     sum = np.zeros(np.size(x))
     for i in np.arange(1, n + 1):
         sum += ((a(i, L) * np.cos((i * np.pi * x) / L)) + (b(i, L) * np.sin((i * np.pi * x) / L)))
     return (a0 / 2) + sum   


 plt.plot(x, f(x))


 plt.plot(x, Sf(x, L))


 plt.show()
```

Comment: Please show your code and your results.

Comment: [numpy.fft](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fft.fft.html#numpy.fft.fft)?

Comment: @DYZ code added

Comment: Since you use numpy, anyway, why not use scipy FFT functions? https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.fft.html

Comment: @DYZ would i need to use the fft or the rfft?

Comment: I dunno. Read the documentation.

Comment: @DYZ ok so now that i have the spectral representation of the signal and i know what the magnitudes are at each harmonics, how do i plot the Fourier series of the signal? so i just produce sin waves that have the magnitude and frequency of each harmonic present in the spectrum?

Comment: You need to evaluate each harmonic with `a*np.sin(np.linspace(...))`, add them up, and plot the sum with `matplotlib.pyplot.plot()`.