# output of a fft expressed as a fourier series in terms of sine/cosine

Tags: python, fft

I'm wondering if anyone can help me better understand the fourier series by seeing the output of a fourier transform actually used as the `coefficients` in the series of `sine` and `cosine` functions.

I have some function, I sample 4 times to get `[0, 1, 0, 1], therefore N == 4`. How do I express this as a fourier series? Using numpy, the fft gives me...`[ 2.+0.j, 0.+0.j, -2.+0.j, 0.+0.j]` Basically, I need to see the expansion of this, NOT in summation notation, just because otherwise I will just have a fear-induced cloudy mind. By expansion, I mean `sin(something * x) + cos(something * x) +` ...

Answer (score 2):

The relationship between the Discrete Fourier Transform (DFT) and Fourier series [can be summarized as follows](http://www.dsprelated.com/freebooks/mdft/Relation_DFT_Fourier_Series.html),

> The Fourier series coefficients of a periodic signal x are given by the DFT of one period of x, divided by N, were N is also the number of samples in each period.

This means that the Fourier series and the DFT are related only if the period of the signal is equal to `N` times its sampling rate, which is not the case in general.

Therefore in practice when you need the DFT, use `scipy.fftpack.fft`, while Fourier series  coefficients can be calculated with [a direct summation in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4258106/1791279). There is plenty of literature on-line about both concepts, but do not mix the two as it will probably be mostly confusing, instead of being helpful.

Comment: I disagree. If you need the Fourier series coefficient of a discretely sampled function, use `fft` to calculate the `dft`: it is far better optimized than any direct summation algorithm. Extracting the Fourier series coefficients from the coefficient of the `dft` is a piece of cake, as I hint above.

Comment: LOL, if you are thorough and look at the other answers in that question you link, I realize now that one of the answers is mine, and actually clarifies in detail the link between DFT and Fourier series coefficients :-)

Comment: @gg349 Well yes, FFT is well optimized and could be used to approximate the DFT.  However, as would be presented in any signal processing textbook the classical way of approaching this topic is: Fourier series -> continuous Fourier transform (FT) -> FT of a sampled signal -> DFT.  My point is that trying to link DFT to the Fourier series is a non trivial task (sampling and finite observation window effects) with underlying assumptions (taking only one period, integer number of samples per period) and is probably best avoided when learning about the DFT.

Comment: Ok, I guess this is a matter of opinion. I find the link very straightforward, and necessary to get the overall picture. In any case, direct summation is not the way to go for a function that is defined only at a finite number of points.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are looking for something like this:

```
from numpy.fft import fft
x = array([ 0.,  1.,  0.,  1.])
y = fft(x)

#first rescale it
nfft = len(x)
y /= nfft

n = arange(0,4)
# notice that y[1] and y[3] are identically zero:
x_reconstructed = y[0] +y[2] * cos(2*2*pi/nfft*n)
```

and now you have `x_reconstructed==x`. Now you can go to the page of the DFT, especially [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform#math_Eq.2) equation, and understand summation notation based on the example above.

Comment: is 2*2*pi/nfft*n meant to create a vector or a scalar in this context?

Comment: n is a vector, so that term will create a vector.