# How do I get a periodic curve fit from discrete data in python?

Tags: python, numpy

I wand to do integration on a dynamic system like to the ODE

```
x_ddot + d*x_dot + k*x = a*sin(omega*t)
```

with one modification: The external force a * sin(omega * t) must be replaced by another periodic signal which is based on some measurement data. That means: I need do curve fitting on my discrete measurement data and the resulting function must be periodic. I had two ideas how to solve the problem:

1) Use Fourier Transform (numpy.fft). But its difficult to generate a continuous function from discrete data using discrete fourier transform.

2) Use curve fitting, with a function like a1+a2*sin(omega*t)+a3*sin(2*omega*t)+a4*sin(.... where omega is 2*pi/(length of measurement data). Unfortunately this wasn't very successful as well. I've tried it with combination of sin and cos terms and went to very high order (...sin(10*omega*t)) which didn't make it better.

[Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/riIm8.png)

I would really appreciate some hints, please see my code with example-data bellow:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math as math
import scipy.special as sp

# create data
f =    [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1.1,1.3,1.7,1.9,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2.1,2.3,2.9,4.1,4.3,4.4,4.5,4.4,4,3.6,3.2,2.8,2.4,2.0,1.6,1.3,1.2,1.1,1,1,1,1,1]
alpha   = np.linspace(0,len(f),len(f))

omega = 2*np.pi/len(f)

def func(alpha, a1, ac2, ac3, ac4, ac5, ac6, ac7):
    fit     = a1 + ac2*np.sin(omega*alpha) + ac3*np.sin(omega*2*alpha) + ac4*np.sin(omega*3*alpha) + ac5*np.sin(omega*4*alpha) +      ac6*np.sin(omega*5*alpha) + ac7*np.sin(omega*6*alpha)
    return fit

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, alpha, f) 

print popt

y_fit= func(alpha,popt[0],popt[1],popt[2],popt[3],popt[4],popt[5],popt[6])

plt.plot(alpha,f,'bo',label='discrete data')
plt.plot(alpha,y_fit,'r',label='periodic fit')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are content with a numerical function, a simple approach based on interpolation is the following:

Step 1: Define an interpolation function based on the data set, which determines one period of the function. (I used the simple `interp1d` from Scipy, more elaborate alternatives are also available in Scipy.)

```
from  scipy.interpolate import interp1d    
f_interp_one_period = interp1d(alpha, f, 'cubic')
```

Step 2: Define a periodic function based on the above (I used as period the value `55` based on the data)

```
def f_periodic(alpha):
        return f_interp_one_period(numpy.mod(alpha,55))
```

The following plot show `f_periodic` over the range -100 to 200, and the original data

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately I think a numerical function is not satisfying my problem. I need something like f(t)=k+a*sin(b*t)+c*sin(d*t)+....because i'm using pydstool

Comment: @PyNoob In that case you can compute the [Fourier series approximation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FourierSeries.html) of the numerical function, which requires determination of the Fourier coefficients. A related post is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4258106/how-to-calculate-a-fourier-series-in-numpy)

Comment: @Stelios consider fitting data as function of angle, going from 0 to 2pi. Is it possible to somehow impose f(0)=f(2pi)? Thank you.