# How to write a python function to generate fourier series like the "fourier" function in R?

Tags: python, r, numpy, forecast

`fourier(series,k)` returns a matrix containing terms from a Fourier series( `cos` and `sin`), up to order `K(parameter)`. How to code a similar function in python?

Answer (score 1):

I can think of 2 options for fast fourier transforms in python:

[scipy FFT](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/tutorial/fft.html)

[numpy FFT](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.fft.html)

you can also refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4258106/how-to-calculate-a-fourier-series-in-numpy)